# RecyclerView behavior - Goes empty when keyboard is opened/closed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-filterable

I have implemented a `RecyclerView` with `SearchView` and `Filterable`; all classes from `v7`. Now there is this behavior that is annoying. Whenever the keyboard is brought up or closed the contents of the `RecyclerView` goes blank. The count is still correct but the view is empty. My guess, it has something to do with the `Layout` size change. Is this behavior normal or something is wrong? How to deal with it? I can show the code but don't quite know which part will be relevant so tell me what can I add here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While typing in the question, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455424/recyclerview-show-wrong-when-the-keyboard-open) from the similar questions.

> Please add following line to your activity in manifest. Hope it works. android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

More precisely, add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the `activity` tag in `AndroidMenifest.xml` where the keyboard is going to be opened.

**Example:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".FManagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It is basically the behavior in which the activity reacts when the keyboard is opened or closed. `adjustPan` tells the keyboard to overlay the view of the activity not disturbing it's content. Without that when the keyboard is opened the size of the activity also changes which makes the content disappear as `notifyDatasetChanged()` is not called during and after the implicit actions.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why but setting it as ***SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE*** solved the issue for me:

```
activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

Comment: Setting `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` will resize the activity which will lead to recreation of activity (unless handling manually using `android:configChanges="screenSize"`). You must save activity state and retain in `onCreate`.