# RecyclerView items disappears after soft keyboard popup

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard

New to Kotlin here and got this problem -

I have a Fragment with recycler view that holds lists - ListsFragment, in my test case it holds 6 lists.
Clicking on a list will invoke a second Fragment - ItemsFragment.
ItemsFragment displays an EditText and recycler with the items belong to the list, in my test case, 2 items per list.

In the **onCreateView** of ItemsFragment, I am using this code to get the recycler of ListsFragment -

```
val fragManager = activity?.supportFragmentManager
val frag = fragManager?.findFragmentByTag("tag_main")
listsRecycler = (frag?.view as View).lists_recycler_view
```

when looking at listRecycler in Debug, all looks good, I can see the 6 lists -
[listRecycler at onCreateView of ItemsFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K2uu.jpg)

After I hit the enter key and looking again at listRecycler in Debug, **now I can only see 4 lists** -
[listRecycler at setOnKeyListener of ItemsFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd6jS.jpg)

I have a "theory" why it happens -
When the two items are displayed, they are on top of the 6 lists from the ListFragment, when I click on the EditText the soft keyboard pop up and "wipe" the last 2 lists from ListFragment, is it possible?

ItemsFragment complete code -

```
class ItemsFragment : Fragment()  {
lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
var table1 = mutableListOf<Items>()
lateinit var toolbar  : Toolbar
lateinit var theView  : View
lateinit var listsRecycler : RecyclerView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false)

    var txt_add_item = theView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txt_add_item)

    txt_add_item.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            makeToast()
            true
        }
        false
    })

    val fragManager = activity?.supportFragmentManager
    val frag = fragManager?.findFragmentByTag("tag_main")
    listsRecycler = (frag?.view as View).lists_recycler_view

    return theView
}

fun makeToast() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Enter Key Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onStart () {
    super.onStart()
    var anItem = Items()
    anItem.itemName = "Item 1"
    table1.add(0, anItem)

    anItem = Items()
    anItem.itemName = "Item 2"
    table1.add(1, anItem)
    viewAdapter = ItemsAdapter(table1)
    items_recycler_view.adapter = viewAdapter
}
```

Adapter for ListFragment -

```
class ListsAdapter(private val logList: MutableList<Lists>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val txvLog : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_name)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.txvLog.text = logList[position].listName

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
        val context = v.context
        val activity = context as AppCompatActivity
        var fragment = ItemsFragment()
        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add((R.id.frame_layout), fragment, "tag_list")
            .commit()
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int { return logList.size }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

man. Welcome to stackoverflow. Basically this happen because the content has to react to the new screen size. I suggest you to read this question [RecyclerView behavior - Goes empty when keyboard is opened/closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069334/recyclerview-behavior-goes-empty-when-keyboard-is-opened-closed)
it might helps you. Basically the suggestions are: a) save state b) add some code to manifest.

Comment: Thanks! you are right, this is probably what happens, I already have "AdjustPan" in my activity but this problem still occurs in my fragment...

Comment: If you use the following line of code in your onstart method it'll probably fix it:
adapter.submitList(yourlist)